# Blind image deconvolution

Tags: algorithm, math, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement blind image deconvolution algorithm presented in this paper http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/luyuan/paper/dualdeblur_cvpr08.pdf

But I have some difficulties to understand some parts of the algorithm:

1. How to compute energy function (5)[image]
   B1 * k2 is a matrix, right? So how can I compute (4) on a matrix?
   [image]
2. Also it is not clear how can I compute anisotropic diffusion tensor (9)
   [image]

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: E_d(k_1, k_2) is the sum (integral in the continuous setting) of the values of rho at each spatial location. Thus, the functional to minimize is the sum of the values of rho for each pixel of the image.

For Eq. (9), I propose you a small trick. Anisotropic diffusion in the direction orthogonal to the image gradient (nabla k here) can be implemented as median filtering. So I suggest you to replace the anisotropic diffusion solver by a few iterations of median filtering (i.e., apply it maybe 10 times). This will avoid you to struggle with the math involved here.